# ¿Cómo trabajar con una base de datos existente en entityframework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un proyecto con ***EntityFramework***, pero ha sido trabajado con ***code first*** y tiene su clase *context*, *migrations*, *entidades*, *repository* e *interfaces*. El problema es que necesito trabajar con otra base de datos existente y al crear mi context y mis entidades se generan en la base de datos como tablas y yo no quiero eso porque ya existen esas tablas.Simplemente deseo crear mis repositorios e interfaces y demás y usar las tablas existentes.

Archivo web.config

```
<add name="ContenedoresContext" connectionString="data source=xxx;
       initial catalog=xxx; Integrated Security=True;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Código Context

```
public class ContenedoresContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Ruma> rumas { get; set; }
    }
```

Entidad Ruma

```
public class Ruma
    {
        [Key]
        public int codRuma { get; set; }
        public string nomRuma { get; set; }
        public int estado { get; set; }
    }
```

Interfaz

```
public interface IRumaRepository:IGenericRepository<Ruma>
    {
        IQueryable<Ruma> ListarRumasActivas();
        void EliminarActivos();
    }
```

Clase implementa la interfaz

```
public class RumaRepository:GenericRepository<Ruma,ContenedoresContext>,IRumaRepository
    {
        private DbContext _db = null;
        public RumaRepository(DbContext contexto) : base(contexto)
        {
            _db = contexto as DbContext;
        }


        public IQueryable<Ruma> ListarRumasActivas()
        {
            return this._db.Set<Ruma>();
        }
    }
```

Mi controlador

```
public JsonResult listaTotalRuma()
        {
            var listado = _repo.ListarRumasActivas();
            var resultado = Json(new { data = listado }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            resultado.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return resultado;
        }
```

Necesito usar las tablas existentes para las operaciones crud y no crearlas desde codefirst ya que ya existen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen diferentes `Initializers` que puedes configurar para que no aplique cambios sobre la db existen

[Database Initialization Strategies in EF 6 Code-First](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Para inhabilitarlo asigna un `null` en `Database.SetInitializer<>()`

```
public class ContenedoresContext : DbContext
{
    public ContenedoresContext() : base("ContenedoresContext")
    {            
        Database.SetInitializer<ContenedoresContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Ruma> rumas { get; set; }
}
```

Si necesitas mapear el nombre de la tabla

[Entity Mappings using Fluent API in EF 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx)

utiliza el `ToTable()` en  `OnModelCreating`

Comment: y como puedo mapear mi tabla de la base de datos, se llama TaRuma.Aparte de ello, DbSet Rumas tiene que ir en el context.

Comment: Lo que quiero es evitar mapear desde data entity model y simplemente basarme con lo que ya tengo.

Comment: si la tabla tiene un nombre diferente al que le defines en la propiedad debes indicarlo usando el ToTable(), edite la pregunta y agregue un link en donde veras como lo aplica en el OnModelCreating